# Flutter BLoC - Update state of an ancestor route

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-navigation

So, I use BLoC to manage my app's state. The general behavior is that if some data on a child route is updated, the ancestor parent update (fetch data from an API) again. Also, each route is under a different provider For example,

```
Home()
  |-> DetailsPage1 (Provider 1)
  |-> DetailsPage2 (Provider 2)
           |-> MoreDetailedPage (Provider 5) (update on this should update Home())
```

For a single level of navigation, I have no issue passing a callback function. But that though process isn't scaling well when I have a complicated route hierarchy. I don't think passing around a callback to every state is a good practice.

So, how do I do this? Thank you.

Comment: How are you providing the bloc to each page, I had issues providing bloc with ```BlocProvider()``` and had to use ```BlocProvider.value()``` because the bloc was getting closed in the last page it was used, and no event was called.

Comment: @NelsonThiago These are different providers. I, too, use `BlocProvider.value()` to pass Provider context to child routes.